# How can I enable haptic feedback on my keypad?

Tags: keyboard, phone-app, sony-ericsson-xperia-x8, haptic-feedback

How can I enable haptic feedback on my keypad? By keypad I mean the dial pad thing where you input numbers. I can find an option to turn sound on or off for it but not haptic feedback.

I have the xperia x8 by the way.

Answer (score 8):

It seems somewhat buried, but on my HTC Droid Incredible I navigate to Settings > Language & Keyboard > Touch Input > Text Input. Under Other Settings I can set "Vibrate when typing."

Answer (score 6):

I think Gary's answer is correct for the ordinary keyboard, but on my phone, other haptic feedback is controlled by another setting, equally hidden away at:

Settings > Sound > Vibrate feedback (right at the bottom)

For me (HTC Desire HD), this enables haptic feedback on the dialler keypad, as well as on the touch-sensitive home, menu, back and search buttons.